# How to delete my questions asked on Ask Different

Tags: support

I know how to [delete my account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion), but I haven't found a way to delete the questions I asked. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a „delete“ link at the bottom of each post. If there isn‘t one, you can also flag for mod attention.

Having said that: There isn‘t actually a need to delete questions, the system cleans up unanswered ones automatically. And if there is an answer, it still might be useful to have the question for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I don't see much point in keeping my questions, if I delete my account anyway. Does that only apply to unanswered questions, or all of my questions?

Comment: @AlexIxeras Sorry to see you leave. But if you delete your account, your questions will get attached to an anonymous account ("user1234546"), so there will be no visible connection to you anyway. Auto-deletion only occurs with unanswered questions.

Comment: @AlexIxeras [This one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458743/remind-me-function-not-available-in-mail) for instance has future value, despite the lone downvote you got on the question.